# Can I import an external .css file from a view file (*.ui.xml ) in my GWT project?

Tags: gwt

I wanna know if this is possible. I have an external .css file in my project and in a *.ui.xml file I have my view code, but I don´t wanna put the .css file within the .ui.xml file, so, can I import this external .css to my view code and used It there?.

Comment: What are you reffering to, when you talk about your "view code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. Or as `src` attribute or as client bundle via attribute `type` to `<ui:style>`· See the GWT documentation for more information: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World